Is there a special scalar product for "the real world"?
Euclidean geometry strives to describe the real world and the usual conclusion is that a correct model is a three-dimensional real vector space (or rather an affine space, but let us fix an origin, I also disregard orientations of the spaces) together with a norm which comes from a scalar product. Any two such three-dimensional spaces are isomorphic, i.e., there is a linear bijection which preserves all distance and hence also the scalar product and angles between vectors (this is elementary linear algebra and I have no doubts about it). One may take this as an argument that these spaces are indistinguishable and any one is an equally good model of our world.
In particular, there is nothing which distinguishes $\mathbb R^3$ with the usual dot product $x\cdot y= x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3$ from the sclar product $\langle x,y \rangle= 2x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3$. Saying something like in $(\mathbb R^3,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ the unit vectors no longer form an othonormal basis (because $e_1$ now has length $2$) does not count because an orthonormal basis is not part of the structure of a Eucledian space but only a convenient tool to do calculations. If one draws the unit ball of $(\mathbb R^3,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ in $(\mathbb R^3,\cdot)$ it becomes an ellipsoid somehow because of has
taken a different unit length for the first axis -- but this is only true if one measures the length in $(\mathbb R^3,\cdot)$ and not internally in $(\mathbb R^3,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$.

Is this really the full story or is there some extra strucure of the real world which distinguishes the standard dot product from other scalar products?


To write down a formula for the dot product, you need to choose a basis, which has no physical significance.  In fact there is nothing to distinguish: all three-dimensional inner product spaces are isometric, i.e., there is essentially only one of them.  The different formulas you wrote down are due to different choices of basis.

No, Euclidean geometry does not strive to describe the real world. Instead it has only ever described an idealized concept of the real world. Even the ancient Greek philosophers understood that the real world couldn't match their idealized concept.

Selecting an origin and considering all points as vectors from that origin, the length of a vector $P$ is its distance from the origin, and to find the inner product of $P$ and $Q$, first project $Q$ onto the line through $P$ and the origin, with $Q'$ as the projected point. The inner product of $P$ and $Q$ is the product of the lengths of $P$ and $Q'$. Bases and linear algebra are not needed.
